# enable istream operator>> to accept either two or three values

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to modify the istream operator>> to accept either two or three values.
This is what I have so far:

In this example, Unit is the class that is to be interacted using the istream opeartor>>.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& istream, Unit& unit)
{
  string command;
  int val,val2;
  istream >> command >> val >> val2;
  if(command=="Damage")
  {
    unit.fCurrentHP-=val;
  }
  else if(command=="Heal")
  {
    unit.fCurrentHP+=val;
  }
  else if(command=="Move")
  {
    unit.pos[0]=val;
    unit.pos[1]=val2;
  }
  return istream
}
```

The problem is that when I enter let's say Damage 50, it still expects the second value (val2), how do I make the input selective? Or be able to be dynamic, to be able to accept Damage 50 and update, or accept Move 5 -6 and update?

Comment: You didn't mention a problem. What is it that needs solving?

Comment: @PasserBy whoops, my apologies, I've added it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough, only read the third value when you are sure you need it

```
istream& operator>>(istream& istream, Unit& unit)
{
  string command;
  int val;
  istream >> command >> val;
  if(command=="Damage")
  {
    unit.fCurrentHP-=val;
  }
  else if(command=="Heal")
  {
    unit.fCurrentHP+=val;
  }
  else if(command=="Move")
  {
    int val2;
    istream >> val2; // third value needed
    unit.pos[0]=val;
    unit.pos[1]=val2;
  }
  return istream;
}
```

PS, it's not illegal but naming your variable `istream` the same as the type of the variable (also `istream`) is a recipe for confusion.

PPS also confusing is that you called this function `operator>>`. `>>` is normally used for functions which read whole objects, but your version doesn't read a `Unit` object. It's clear from the code that the `Unit` object already exists and is just being updated by this function. So something like

```
istream& update_unit(istream& istream, Unit& unit)
```

would be a better name for the function.

Comment: @cswannabe warning I encourage you to add error checking

Answer (score 1):

when you do

> ```
>   istream >> command >> val >> val2;
> ```

all the 3 values are read (out of EOF), this is not what you want, you need separated reads

do not forget to test the error cases

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Unit& unit)
{
  string command;
  int val, val2;

  if (! (in >> command))
    ...error
  else if(command=="Damage")
  {
    if (! (in >> val))
      ...error
    else
      unit.fCurrentHP -= val;
  }
  else if(command=="Heal")
  {
    if (! (in >> val))
      ...error
    else
      unit.fCurrentHP += val;
  }
  else if(command=="Move")
  {
    if (! (in >> val >> val2))
      ...error
    else {
      unit.pos[0]=val;
      unit.pos[1]=val2;
    }
  }
  else
    ...error

  return in;
}
```